# UnicodeDecodeError when installing python-igraph

Tags: python, igraph

I'm using python 2.7 on 64-bit Linux Mint 16 and I'm trying to install python-igraph. But when I run `sudo pip install python-igraph` I get the following log:

```
Downloading/unpacking python-igraph
  Downloading python-igraph-0.7.1-1.tar.gz (375kB): 375kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package python-igraph

Installing collected packages: python-igraph
  Running setup.py install for python-igraph
    Build type: dynamic extension
    Include path: /usr/include/igraph
    Library path:
    Linked dynamic libraries: igraph
    Linked static libraries:
    Extra compiler options:
    Extra linker options:
    building 'igraph._igraph' extension
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/igraph -I../../build/include -I../../include -I/usr/local/include/igraph -I/usr/include/igraph -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/igraphmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/igraphmodule.o
    In file included from src/igraphmodule.c:30:0:
    src/convert.h:65:59: error: unknown type name ‘igraph_pagerank_algo_t’
     int igraphmodule_PyObject_to_pagerank_algo_t(PyObject *o, igraph_pagerank_algo_t *result);
                                                               ^
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/python-igraph/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-akm3_O-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed:
    running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph

copying igraph/formula.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph

copying igraph/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph

copying igraph/configuration.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph

copying igraph/summary.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph

copying igraph/layout.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph

copying igraph/cut.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph

copying igraph/datatypes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph

copying igraph/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph

copying igraph/clustering.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph

copying igraph/statistics.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph

copying igraph/matching.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph

copying igraph/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/operators.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/isomorphism.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/colortests.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/conversion.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/homepage.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/attributes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/vertexseq.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/structural.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/separators.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/atlas.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/layouts.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/rng.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/games.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/iterators.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/edgeseq.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/indexing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/spectral.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/cliques.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/flow.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/basic.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/generators.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/matching.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/foreign.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/bipartite.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/decomposition.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/app

copying igraph/app/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/app

copying igraph/app/shell.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/app

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/drawing

copying igraph/drawing/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/drawing

copying igraph/drawing/edge.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/drawing

copying igraph/drawing/shapes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/drawing

copying igraph/drawing/coord.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/drawing

copying igraph/drawing/metamagic.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/drawing

copying igraph/drawing/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/drawing

copying igraph/drawing/text.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/drawing

copying igraph/drawing/graph.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/drawing

copying igraph/drawing/colors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/drawing

copying igraph/drawing/vertex.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/drawing

copying igraph/drawing/baseclasses.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/drawing

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/remote

copying igraph/remote/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/remote

copying igraph/remote/nexus.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/remote

copying igraph/remote/gephi.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/remote

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/vendor

copying igraph/vendor/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/vendor

copying igraph/vendor/texttable.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/igraph/vendor

running build_ext

Build type: dynamic extension

Include path: /usr/include/igraph

Library path:

Linked dynamic libraries: igraph

Linked static libraries:

Extra compiler options:

Extra linker options:

building 'igraph._igraph' extension

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/igraph -I../../build/include -I../../include -I/usr/local/include/igraph -I/usr/include/igraph -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/igraphmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/igraphmodule.o

In file included from src/igraphmodule.c:30:0:

src/convert.h:65:59: error: unknown type name ‘igraph_pagerank_algo_t’

 int igraphmodule_PyObject_to_pagerank_algo_t(PyObject *o, igraph_pagerank_algo_t *result);

                                                           ^

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/python-igraph/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-akm3_O-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/python-igraph
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.4.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 148, in main
    return command.main(args[1:], options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 169, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 50: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I previously installed libigraph0-dev. How can I install python-igraph in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Does the version of `libigraph0-dev` match the version number of the Python interface? If the version of `libigraph0-dev` is not equal to 0.7.1, it will not be suitable for the version of `python-igraph` that you are trying to compile. In that case, it is better to remove `libigraph0` and `libigraph0-dev` and run `pip install python-igraph` again; the setup script will then attempt to download and compile an appropriate version of the C core of igraph first.

I know that you have posted another question today in which you stated that `pip install python-igraph` (without having `libigraph0-dev`) does not work for you; try again anyway because the previous version of `python-igraph` had a bug that prevented it from downloading the right version of the C core, and I have fixed the bug just an hour ago.

Comment: After removing libigraph0, I ran pip again and it outputted huge log that terminated with an error. End of this log: `Could not download and compile the C core of igraph. WARNING: we were not able to detect where igraph is installed on your machine (if it is installed at all). We will use the fallback library and include pathss hardcoded in setup.py and hope that the C core of igraph is installed there.` ... `src/igraphmodule.c:25:20: fatal error: igraph.h: No such file or directory #include <igraph.h> compilation terminated. error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1`
`

Comment: It works for me so please post the full compilation log somewhere so I can take a look at it.

Comment: You can take it at it here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bv5soo02xvos9oz/log.txt?dl=0

Comment: Okay, the problem is actually that you will have to install `libxml2-dev` in order to compile the C core of igraph (because the GraphML reader needs it). This is reported correctly by the install log, the problem is that the compilation continues nevertheless (while it should have stopped) and the error message is buried in the middle of the log.

Comment: @Tamás Can you please please please put that requirement on the official documentation here if you have that power:  http://igraph.org/python/  igraph will not install on Ubuntu or most Debian distros without this and it was the hardest thing ever to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

download source code of [igraph in C](http://igraph.org/c)  and install it using below code

```
./configure && make && sudo make install
```

then install python igraph using pip or from source