# Unable to install Python-igraph using pip in ubuntu

Tags: igraph

I got following error when I am trying to install python-igraph using `sudo pip install python-igraph`

`Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-ZHOdbM/python-igraph/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-MGaN23-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ZHOdbM/python-igraph/`

I also try to install C core using the link given in the answer [UnicodeDecodeError when installing python-igraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28440061/unicodedecodeerror-when-installing-python-igraph)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use conda and the following command :

```
conda install -c conda-forge python-igraph
```

https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/python-igraph